# Animate elements sequencially when in viewport on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with multiple rows of divs I want to animate in sequentially from left to right with a short time offset between each item, but only when the row is in the viewport on scroll. I do not want to group them into rows in the html since the items need to be 4 items per row, 3 items per row ect... based on screen size.

I basically want to do the below code but only on the row in the viewport and when scrolled down the page, animate the next row in the viewport ect...

```
$('.gallery-item').each(function(i){
    $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(400, 1);
});
```

To see the effect I'm looking to achieve take a loot at firstborn studios work page
http://www.firstborn.com/work/featured

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply add a line to check if the element is outside the viewport? We can assume that all the elements in the viewport are before the elements outside the viewport (hopefully), so you can do this:

```
$('.gallery-item').each(function(i){
    if($(this).offset().top > window.innerHeight) 
        return false;
    $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(400, 1);
});
```

We simply cancel the loop once an element is outside the viewport. You could even do a double check if you want to so it will do it for al elements inside the viewport regardless of its position in the flow:

```
$('.gallery-item').each(function(i){
    if( 
        $(this).offset().top < window.scrollTop + window.innerHeight
        && $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.scrollTop
    ) $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(400, 1);
});
```

This will only execute if the elements top is inside the viewport, or its bottom is.

Comment: Option 1 - only loads in the divs which are initially in the viewport and then stops. Calling the load function again on scroll does not continue to load subsequent divs. Option 2 doesn't fire any to show

Comment: Wait you are asking how to make this happen _as you scroll_ as that is an entirely different question. But the answer could be simple - you just need to mark the ones that are done and ignore them (maybe using a `:not` query and adding a class to ones that have completed their animations), then run this script on scroll.

Comment: hmmm... maybe starting with a class of "invisible" on all divs and as it iterates through each one on in the viewport swap classes to a "visible" class then on scroll fire the function again

Comment: Possibly. To be honest, in that case I would simply loop through all your elements on scroll, assign them a class like `in-viewport` and do your animations using css `transitions` - it will be much more efficient as the browser optimises the transitions, but not the js animations.

Comment: I was actually planning on changing to transitions since I noticed an unwanted effect happen while hovering one of the gallery items. On hover, all siblings dim down, but while they are loading all the invisible elements just appear